# Reset Interval and refire function

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

Im using a plugin called Flapper.js which animates text/numbers like a airport style board.

I want it to cycle through an array of words which works fine. But i also have a restart ticker button, which conflicts with the setInterval i have set up.

my code is

```
    window.setInterval(function(){
        var messages = ["INSPIRE", "EMPOWER", "EVOLVE", "ENCHANCE", "CHANGE LIVES"],
        message = messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
        $('.flap').remove();
        $(".ticker .fixedGuide h2").after("<input type='text' value='abcde' class='flap light S'>")
        $(".flap").flapper(opts).val(message).change();
    }, 5000);

    $('.restartTicker').click(function() {
        var messages = ["INSPIRE", "EMPOWER", "EVOLVE", "ENCHANCE", "CHANGE LIVES"],
        message = messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
        $('.flap').remove();
        $(".ticker .fixedGuide h2").after("<input type='text' value='abcde' class='flap light S'>")
        $(".flap").flapper(opts).val(message).change();
    });
```

What happens when i click the .resetTicker button is that the airport style board updates just how i want it to, but then the setInterval script is still running so if i click the restartTicker button after 3 seconds, 2 seconds later it updates again. where i want it to restart the setInterval back to 0.

Comment: did we answer your question by chance or are you still having issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know flapper, so I'm not positive this will work, but normally to reset an interval you need to assign the interval to a variable like this:

```
var myInterval = window.setInterval(function(){
    var messages = ["INSPIRE", "EMPOWER", "EVOLVE", "ENCHANCE", "CHANGE LIVES"],
    message = messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
    $('.flap').remove();
    $(".ticker .fixedGuide h2").after("<input type='text' value='abcde' class='flap light S'>")
    $(".flap").flapper(opts).val(message).change();
}, 5000);

$('.restartTicker').click(function() {
    clearInterval(myInterval);

    myInterval = window.setInterval(function(){
        var messages = ["INSPIRE", "EMPOWER", "EVOLVE", "ENCHANCE", "CHANGE LIVES"],
        message = messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
        $('.flap').remove();
        $(".ticker .fixedGuide h2").after("<input type='text' value='abcde' class='flap light S'>")
        $(".flap").flapper(opts).val(message).change();
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: Hi, this code works kinda of how i want it to. although one problem, when you click the ".restartTicker" you have to wait 5 seconds before it works due to the myInterval set onclick. i want the rotation to be 5 seconds apart, but when you click the restart button, it changes straight away and then every 5 seconds . if that makes sense.

Comment: Ok i got it working how i wanted. Not sure if its the best way but it works

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see this sooner.  Glad you got it working.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Set the interval to a variable

```
var x = window.setInterval( ... );
```

Then you can clear it by `x.clearInterval`. This will stop it from running, and then you can just recall the interval to start it once more.